# Align text in equation

Tags: positioning, vertical-alignment

```
\begin{align*}
    \text{min }  \mu \  \\
    \text{s.t. }    P^t(X)  &\le y_t,\ (\forall t \in T)\\
                        \sum_{t \in M_k} y_t &\le \mu , \ 0 \leq k \leq k_{max}\ & \\
                       \mu  &\ge 0, y_t \geq 0
\end{align*}
```

I want the top `\mu` be aligned over `y_t` and the `min` next to `\mu`.

Comment: Isn't the condition `\mu \ge 0` redundant at it's implied by the conditions `y_t \ge 0` and `\sum y_t \le \mu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description isn't so clear, but perhaps this. Note you should avoid `\` in math mode, and don't use `math italic for multi-letter works such as`max`and just use`\text` for text phrases, not math operators.

Also, please always post complete documents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &\min  \mu \\
    \text{s.t. }    P^t(X)  &\le y_t,\ (\forall t \in T)\\
                        \sum_{t \in M_k} y_t &\le \mu , \ 0 \leq k \leq k_{\max}& \\
                       \mu  &\ge 0, y_t \geq 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In comments You indicate that you want the version below but the alignment in either case
seems suboptimal and unrelated to the meaning. I'd center the constraints under the expression "min \mu" ther isn't really any logical alignment between the \mu and y.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \min {}& \mu \\
    \text{s.t. }    P^t(X)  \le {}&y_t,\ (\forall t \in T)\\
                        \sum_{t \in M_k} y_t \le {}&\mu , \ 0 \leq k \leq k_{\max}& \\
                       \mu  \ge {}&0, y_t \geq 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: okay!! but now $\mu$ is slightly right over $y_t$

Comment: @user3613886 see update

Comment: yes that looks so much better!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use alignment characters for this, because as your equations get more complex, you might want to align the equals signs or something and that'll break it.

This uses `\overbracket` and `\overbrace` from `\mathtools` so that the alignment of the align environment isn't effected:

> [image]

The first example draws a brace over the text you're writing about for completeness' sake, and the second is what you asked for, text floating above the term in question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \text{s.t. }    P^t(X)  &\le \overbrace{y_t,}^{\text{min\ }\mu}\ (\forall t \in T)\\
                        \sum_{t \in M_k} y_t &\le \mu , \ 0 \leq k \leq k_{max}\ & \\
                       \mu  &\ge 0, y_t \geq 0
\end{align*}

With brace drawing suppressed:
\begin{align*}
    \text{s.t. }    P^t(X)  &\le \overbracket[0pt]{y_t,}^{\text{min\ }\mu}\ (\forall t \in T)\\
                        \sum_{t \in M_k} y_t &\le \mu , \ 0 \leq k \leq k_{max}\ & \\
                       \mu  &\ge 0, y_t \geq 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```